Difference between Compilation and Release/Debug in Visual Studio
In Visual Studio, you have at the top, a top down with Release/Debug options and also in the web.config a setting called Compilation where there is a setting called Debug where the values are true and false.  What are the differences between the two and which should you do when releasing the website into production?

There's a defined symbol named DEBUG that's present in debug builds and not in non-debug builds. I believe that that is what the web.config setting keys off of. Debug builds also turn of most optimizations and embed more debugging information (try doing line by line debugging on a release build, it's much more frustrating). Release build are intended to use fewer resources and be as fast as possible. Debug builds are designed to make debugging easier. All this is tunable (or screw-up-able) by the programmer

Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-set-debug-and-release-configurations?view=vs-2022

The #DEBUG is dependent on the Visual Studio drop down not web.config.  I don't understand the purpose of both of them as it stands, why there is two options, the web.config and the drop down.  When releasing, do you need to set both to "Release"

When you deploy old stuff like pre Core Asp.Net or classic Razor code the webserver (IIS mostly) needs to compile parts of that. IIS only knows web.config at runtime and will use that for compilation. So VS will use compiletime settings from projects file and the webserver will use webconfig for runtime compilation,  Didn't do it since a decade but the rule was to keep the settings in sync.
